# XSL transformation with MSXML and whitespace between tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, msxml

I'm doing a pretty standard XSLT transformation. When using MSXML (in Oxygen XML editor), I get following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProgramSchedules mediaCompanyID="00001" date="2017-06-08" channel="00019">
<Schedules>
<Schedule contentId="T17ADiamond008P2AA" startTime="06:29:56" endTime="06:30:11" rerun="true" eventType="AP">
</Schedule>
<Schedule contentId="T17AOslo-Sk236s1AA" startTime="06:30:11" endTime="06:30:31" rerun="true" eventType="AP">
</Schedule>
```

MSXML 4 and Saxon show following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProgramSchedules mediaCompanyID="00001" date="2017-06-08" channel="00019">
<Schedules>
<Schedule contentId="T17ADiamond008P2AA" startTime="06:29:56" endTime="06:30:11" rerun="true" eventType="AP"></Schedule>
<Schedule contentId="T17AOslo-Sk236s1AA" startTime="06:30:11" endTime="06:30:31" rerun="true" eventType="AP"></Schedule>
```

The problem here is that my XML schema does not validate the first output, because of the CRLF that is present after the opening tag.

Is there a way to solve this without changing the processor?

Here's what my stylesheet looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ProgramSchedules>
            <xsl:attribute name="mediaCompanyID">
                <xsl:text>00001</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="date">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="txevents/search-criteria/dateselection/ES_DATESELECTION/firstvalue/ESP_DATE"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="channel">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with(txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/channel/ESP_CHANNEL/@name, 'NRK1')">
                        <xsl:text>00019</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/channel/ESP_CHANNEL/@name = 'NRK2'">
                        <xsl:text>00029</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when
                        test="txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/channel/ESP_CHANNEL/@name = 'NRK3' or txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT/channel/ESP_CHANNEL/@name = 'SUPER'">
                        <xsl:text>00039</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <Schedules>
                <xsl:for-each select="txevents/ES_BMTXEVENT">
                    <Schedule>
                        <xsl:attribute name="contentId">
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate(@productcode, '/', '')"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(transmission/ES_TRANSMISSION/@productVersionAsString, 2, 4)"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="startTime">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="starttime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="endTime">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="endtime/ESP_TIMEDURATION"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="rerun">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when
                                    test="(transmission/ES_TRANSMISSION/@tx_isrepeat = 'true') or (transmission/ES_TRANSMISSION/@tx_isrerun = 'true')">
                                    <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="eventType">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when
                                    test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Segment of program'">
                                    <xsl:text>RP</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Trailer'">
                                    <xsl:text>AP</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Sting/Vignett'">
                                    <xsl:text>RP</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when
                                    test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Klokke NRK1 m/ tekst'">
                                    <xsl:text>IF</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Klokke NRK Super'">
                                    <xsl:text>IF</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Klokke NRK2'">
                                    <xsl:text>IF</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Plakater 3'">
                                    <xsl:text>IF</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'A1 fl on'">
                                    <xsl:text>AP</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'Sponsor'">
                                    <xsl:text>BR</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'TTV-rulle NRK1'">
                                    <xsl:text>IF</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="timeallocation/ES_BMTIMEALLOCATION/type/ESP_BMTIMEALLOCATIONTYPE/@name = 'TTV-rulle NRK2'">
                                    <xsl:text>IF</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:text>US</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:attribute></Schedule>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Schedules>
        </ProgramSchedules>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ESP_TIMEDURATION">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@hours, '00')"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@minutes, '00')"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@seconds, '00')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ESP_DATE">
        <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@month, '00')"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@day, '00')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ESP_TIMEINSTANT">
        <xsl:value-of select="@year"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@month, '00')"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@day, '00')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Raw XML data is here: https://pastebin.com/RWGEi59c

Comment: Can you also show your input XML in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Input data added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of experimentation in Oxygen XML v17.1 shows that a simple change in your XSL can get rid of that annoying newline.

On line 31 of your XSL code, you have the single instruction to insert a `<Schedule>` element, followed by a newline, and line 32:

```
                <Schedule>
                    <xsl:attribute name="contentId">
```

Remove the newline at the end of line 31, so that line 31 and line 32 are combined to look like this instead:

```
                <Schedule><xsl:attribute name="contentId">
```

Theoretically, this should be functionally equivalent, but older MSXML versions appear to be a bit idiosyncratic.